# SQLCmd Hanging On Complex Batch Scripts

Tags: sql-server-2005, deployment, sqlcmd

My company is currently using the sqlcmd 2005 for deployment and for some reason on certain SQL scripts it tends to hang even though there are no errors, and if run from management studio it completes successfully.

It tends to hang on complex scripts that have multiple GO statements and or cursors.

By "hang" I mean the process will not complete until I explicitly kill it with Task Manager.

Has anybody else had this experience, and have any suggestions to work around this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLCMD doesn't seem to like multiple select statements.  When I comment them out it doesn't hang anymore.